# VM automated in Gradle

Tags: svn, gradle

How can I Update my VM using Gradle ?
I try to updated my VM using Gradle but because I am new in Gradle World, i don't know how can i do it.
I have implemented this code but isn't working.

I cam this error "Task 'getSvnRevision' not found in root project"

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
                mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit',name: 'svnkit', version: '1.8.5'
    }
}
allprojects {
    version = '1.2.3.' + getSvnRevision()
}

task update{
    doLast{
            def getSvnRevision(){
                    ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
                    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
                    SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
                    SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
                    SVNRevision revision = status.getRevision();>                   return revision.getNumber();
                                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare any task called `getSvnRevision`, so you of course cannot execute it. You declare a task called `update`, but it doesn't do anything actually, you just define a method in the action block.

I'd guess you mix two approaches you read about, one to call the `update` task that gets the revision and updates some file and one that always gets the revision dynamically on each Gradle call.

Besides that, your code would not even compile, it is syntactically invalid with that greater-than sign.

You should really read [User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) to get a grip on Gradle.